# images inside div having good looking style

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there is a way to make my images inside div look as in the picture . For example , if there is more than two pictures inside the div , one image will be the biggest and the other will divide the width of the biggest image .In addition , if there is four images ,they must look like a square . Please check the image .
Note : I will retreive the images from the database

[image]

Comment: There is a way, sure. What have you tried, where is your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without you providing any code, I can only offer what works rather than what you might specifically want. One method to achieve this would be through flex.

By defining a width and height, then making the img height set to grow with the flex, you can have it adapt to the 4 images you would want. I included a jsfiddle providing an example. Hope you enjoy!

```
.box {
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f8zaav92/

Comment: By not providing code, the question should not be answered at all as it is off topic. [Not all questions can or should be answered.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Rob It does not state in 'How to answer -> Not all questions can or should be answered' that users of SO should not answer a question if the question does not contain code. I think you should take a look at [Be nice](http://www.google.com/) especially section 2.) & 3.)

Comment: @Kitson88 It is very clear by stating, "Not all questions ... should be answered." and not providing code is a checkbox for us to close questions.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: CSS is NOT the right tool for conditional rendering.
So when we finish with formality, i have a pretty good idea how to make everything work ;) Please check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mznw3bmj/2/).

```
img:nth-last-child(n):first-child{ .. }
```

For detailed information follow [this link](https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css)